# Counting the dimension

Tags: combinatorics

Let $A_d^m:=\{\alpha\in \mathbb{N}^d: |\alpha|\leq m\}$, then the cardinality of $A_d^m$ is $\frac{(m+d)!}{m!d!}$.

How is it true? I understand we have to choose $m$ such tuples but how are we choosing them from $m+d$ numbers?

Comment: What do you mean by $|\alpha|$?

Comment: Oh, my mistake. $|\alpha|=\sum_{i=1}^d\alpha_i$

Comment: Also, you used $\mathbb N$, is $0 \in \mathbb N$? If so, are you sure that you were given that $|\alpha| \leqslant m$ instead of $|\alpha| = m?$

Comment: Yes, $0\in \mathbb{N}$. Because if we take $d=m=2$, then $\alpha=(0,0),(0,1),(1,0),(1,1),(2,0),(0,2)$. Which satisfies the lemma

Comment: You should edit your question to include the definition of $|\alpha|$.  Crucial information should be stated in the question rather than in the comments.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You want to count the number of solutions to the inequality
$$
\alpha_1+\alpha_2+\dots+\alpha_d\le m, \qquad \alpha_i \ge 0
$$
Introducing a dummy variable $b$ equal to $m-\alpha_1-\dots-\alpha_2$, this is equivalent to solving
$$
\alpha_1+\dots+\alpha_d+b=m,\qquad\alpha_i\ge0,b\ge0
$$
This is equivalent to counting the number of ways to put $m$ identical balls in $d+1$ distinct bins, which can be solved using [stars and bars](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stars_and_bars_(combinatorics)) to be the claimed answer.